# Can I use dual 4k Dell P2815Q monitors on the Retina MacBook Pro (late 2013) with Yosemite at full resolution?

Tags: display, macbook-pro, thunderbolt, hdmi

1. Will this monitor plug-and-play with Yosemite on this MacBook model without having to install [Xcode and mess around](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/we-made-24-inch-retina-display-3496603/) with creating custom settings?
2. Can I have **two** of these plugged into this MacBook and run them **both** at 4k (at either 30Hz or 60Hz)? - I don't care so much about refresh rates as I do about resolution.  I won't be gaming or watching movies on them.

Answer (score 2):

This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt.

Alternately, it can support a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI.

Comment: FYI: The underlying hardware is supposedly capable of handling 4K monitors. But I've yet to see an clear proof of the MacBook Pro (Retina, late 2013) actually working with 4K monitors. The Answer above is correct according the [Apple specs page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP690?locale=en_US). But some of us wonder if that really is the limit.